# Simple Reshape of a 9061x16 into 6x24x??x16 (4D). Data included, [MATLAB]

Tags: arrays, matlab

i have a matrix og 9061x16 i want to reshape to 6x24x??x16. currently the 9061x16 explains this: 16 is the amount of customers.. and 9061 is how much data each customer have.

What i want from the reshape:

since the data is collected every 10 min. for a duration of 62 days and some hours which the ?? is. Since in 1 hour there is collected 6 data. the matrix will therefore be like 6x24xdaysx16..

please do help i really need this :(.

the x.mat is what i reshaped 9061x16 from the V.mat

(The data can be downloaded from this post: [Data of x.mat and v.mat](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/128295-simple-reshape-of-a-9061x16-into-6x24x-x16-4d-data-included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend `x` to a number of rows multiple of 6*24, and then use `reshape`:

```
x(ceil(size(x,1)/144)*144, end) = 0; %// extend x, filling with zeros
x = reshape(x, 6, 24, [], 16); %// reshape x into desired form
```

Comment: Thanks...exactly what i wanted. :D